# Insert Advanced Custom Fields Rule to post_meta table

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm inserting custom fields to postmeta table if the post title is equal to "Components" or "Landing page".

Inside my `add_post_meta()` function I'm getting the serialized data with extra string at the beginning with double quote and at the end double quote with a semicolon.

Expected `a:5:{s:5:"param";s:4:"post";s:8:"operator";s:2:"==";s:5:"value";i:3309;s:8:"order_no";i:0;s:8:"group_no";i:1;}`
Currently inserting `s:110:"a:5:{s:5:"param";s:4:"post";s:8:"operator";s:2:"==";s:5:"value";i:3309;s:8:"order_no";i:0;s:8:"group_no";i:1;}";`

Here is my code:

```
if ($menupost->post_title == "Components" || $menupost->post_title == "Landing Page") {
                global $wpdb;
                $posttitle = 'Tablet';
                $postid_ofacf = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '" . $posttitle . "' and post_type='acf'");
                $post_meta = get_post_meta($postid_ofacf, "rule", false);
                $post_count = count($post_meta);
                $last_array = $post_meta[$post_count - 1];
                $insert_acf_rule_meta = array();
                foreach ($last_array as $key => $value) {
                    if ($key == "group_no") {
                        $value = $value + 1;
                    }
                    if ($key == "value") {
                        $value = $post_id;
                    }
                    $insert_acf_rule_meta[$key] = $value;
                }
                add_post_meta($postid_ofacf, 'rule', serialize($insert_acf_rule_meta));

                $get_acf_post_args = array(
                    'post_title' => 'Tablet',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_type' => 'acf'
                );
            }
```

- How to insert a proper serialized sting as expected.
- Like I'm inserting rule of "Tablet" Custom field to the postmeta table for the posts with title "Components" OR "Landing page", I need to insert some more custom fields(Desktop,Mobile) rules to the postmeta table.
  Any help may greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to pass the serialized array as a parameter to the `add_post_meta` function, as it calls `serialize` function in case an array is given, as stated in the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta).

Rewrite the line:

```
add_post_meta($postid_ofacf, 'rule', serialize($insert_acf_rule_meta));
```

To:

```
add_post_meta($postid_ofacf, 'rule', $insert_acf_rule_meta);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: 1st issue is resolved, How can approach the issue that i specified in the second point.

Comment: Hi @Sha, sorry, I don't seem to understand the second part of your question, isn't that something you can achieve by configuring ACF or can't you add it to the `$get_acf_post_args` array?

Comment: I have created an array and looping through each post titles to insert acf rule.

Comment: @Sha, well, let's get back to the "X problem", what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: And a couple of advises if you don't mind:
Store post titles in the options instead of hardcoding;
Please consider using `$wpdb`  [prepared statements](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/).

Comment: I rectified that 2nd issue myself.

Comment: Glad to hear that:)